# login screen only shows guest

Tags: login-screen

I'm using Xubuntu and now the login dialog box shows Guest instead of my login name.  I've been all over the net and read what lightdm documentation I could find but have not found a solution, let alone how the greeter decides what to put up on that login dialog box.  Can anyone provide some guidance?

EDIT:
It seems that the problem is caused by a UID less than 1000, although changing the UID back to 1000 does not revert the behavior - the greeter wants to login a guest.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/331776/login-loop-can-only-login-as-guest-ubuntu-12-04#379988  

I know its ubuntu but the procedures should be the same

Comment: Did you make any changes to your system or profile immediately before this happened?

Comment: @Cyber_Star - yes, I have tried everything I could find on the net

Comment: @Joseph - I moved the install to a different partition, fixing up grub and fstab, and changing hid:gid to match the servers I use.  I need to find out what file is involved in presenting that login dialog box but can't find that information anywhere.

Comment: By hid:gid, do you mean uid:gid? If so, that's almost certainly what did it. What did you change them to, and are you sure you changed them everywhere?

Comment: @JosephSible re: hid:gid - I hate typing correctors.  Yes - typo.  Yes - everywhere.  I used chown -R uid:gid home_dir like always. If that is the problem, where is the old uid stashed so I can fix it? Failing that, how can I get Ubuntu to let me specify uid:gid?  Or is it that greeter ignores any uid less than 1000? If so, where is that checked?

Answer (score 0):

The greeter ignores users with UIDs of under 1000, so when you changed your user's UID to less than that, it disappeared. I personally recommend that you fix it by putting its UID back. If you can't do that, [How to make users with UID under 1000 appear in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211087/how-to-make-users-with-uid-under-1000-appear-in-lightdm) gives some ways that apparently will let you show it anyway.

Comment: Thanks very much for the link.  I have searched for hours and did not find that one.  Putting the UID back causes more problems than having to choose other to log in.  I strongly suspect this is the answer

Comment: Nope - users.conf was already set to 500 minimum and changing login.defs had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

**From the Recovery Mode** you can add another user to your login screen using these steps.
*(Press ESC when booting to bring up the grub menu.)*

**Bring up the grub boot menu.**

(Select) **Advance** -> **ENTER** -> (select) **Recovery Mode** -> **ENTER** -> (select) **Drop to root shell prompt** -> **ENTER** -> **ENTER**

At the prompt type these commands:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
# adduser testuser
# addgroup testuser sudo
# exit
```

Now on the GUI continue with:

(Select)  **Resume** -> **ENTER** -> **ENTER**

Now login using the newly created account and perform your maintenance.